# Using pivot (Oracle) sql to group it by Parent and child Columns not Sum() but maybe Max() aggregate?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I spend some time to solve this but no luck as im not so familiar on which aggregate functions and pivot approach i should use to get the output below. Raw Table is something like this:

```
ID  | PARENT_ID  |  VALUES
----------------------------------
1   |   NULL     | PARENT A
2   |   1        | CHILD A
3   |   1        | CHILD A        
4   |   NULL     | PARENT B
5   |   4        | CHILD B
6   |   4        | CHILD B
7   |   4        | CHILD B
8   |   4        | CHILD B
9   |   4        | CHILD B
10  |   4        | CHILD B
11  |   4        | CHILD B
126 |   null     | PARENT C
34  |   126      | CHILD C
12  |   126      | CHILD C
13  |   126      | CHILD C
```

I tried using this code but it seems it is not applicable to what I needed exactly :

```
Select
    col1,
    col,
    trunc((rank() over (order by col)-1)/5) as d,
    mod(rank() over (order by col)-1,5) as m
  from
  (
    select col1, col2 as col from table1
     union
    select col1, col3 as col from table1 
  )
;
```

I think this can be done via pivot but i am not that familiar on how to approach it to be like this result table below. Should spread out the row dynamically into columns up to 6 cols.

I have Little to zero knowledge on table manipulations like this. Thanks in advance!!

```
PARENTS    |   CH1    |  CH2     | CH3     | CH4     | CH5     |  CH6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
PARENT A   | CHILD A1 | CHILD A1 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
PARENT B   | CHILD B  | CHILD B  | CHILD B |CHILD B  | CHILD B | CHILD B
           | CHILD B  | NULL     | NULL    |NULL     | NULL    | NULL
PARENT C   | CHILD C  | CHILD C  | CHILD C |NULL     | NULL    | NULL
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: currently using oracle, sorry i'll edit my post

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT parent,
       ch1,
       ch2,
       ch3,
       ch4,
       ch5,
       ch6
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id    AS parent_id,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT value AS parent,
         value,
         MOD(
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT id ORDER BY id) - 1,
           6
         ) + 1 AS child_num,
         TRUNC(
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT id ORDER BY id) - 1)
           / 6
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH parent_id IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR child_num IN (
    1 AS CH1,
    2 AS CH2,
    3 AS CH3,
    4 AS CH4,
    5 AS CH5,
    6 AS CH6
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, PARENT_ID, VALUE) AS
SELECT   1, NULL, 'PARENT A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   2,    1, 'CHILD A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   3,    1, 'CHILD A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   4, NULL, 'PARENT B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   5,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   6,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   7,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   8,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   9,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  10,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  11,    4, 'CHILD B'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 126, NULL, 'PARENT C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  34,  126, 'CHILD C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  12,  126, 'CHILD C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  13,  126, 'CHILD C'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PARENT | CH1 | CH2 | CH3 | CH4 | CH5 | CH6 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | PARENT A | CHILD A | CHILD A | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | PARENT B | CHILD B | CHILD B | CHILD B | CHILD B | CHILD B | CHILD B |
> | PARENT B | CHILD B | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | PARENT C | CHILD C | CHILD C | CHILD C | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e43d4ca11a7a8bba584a6078c3158478)*

Comment: Hi sir, im sorry im so noob that I could not substitute the following , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF , CONNECT_BY_ROOT  into my test table . im using oracle and could you please explain what are these? thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you finally got it!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample data you had provided, you can use a `PIVOT` to build the table into the format that you are looking for.

```sql
WITH
    raw_table (id, parent_id, vals)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, NULL, 'PARENT A' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 1, 'CHILD A' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 1, 'CHILD A' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, NULL, 'PARENT B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 7, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 8, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 9, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 11, 4, 'CHILD B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 126, NULL, 'PARENT C' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 34, 126, 'CHILD C' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 12, 126, 'CHILD C' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 13, 126, 'CHILD C' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t2.vals                                                        AS parent_name,
               t1.vals                                                        AS child_name,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY t2.vals ORDER BY t1.vals)     AS child_num
          FROM raw_table t1 LEFT JOIN raw_table t2 ON (t1.parent_id = t2.id))
       PIVOT (MIN (child_name) ch FOR child_num IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));


   PARENT_NAME        1_CH        2_CH        3_CH       4_CH       5_CH       6_CH       7_CH
______________ ___________ ___________ ___________ __________ __________ __________ __________
PARENT A       CHILD A     CHILD A
PARENT B       CHILD B     CHILD B     CHILD B     CHILD B    CHILD B    CHILD B    CHILD B
PARENT C       CHILD C     CHILD C     CHILD C
               PARENT A    PARENT B    PARENT C
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your solution I will try it, but can this extra "Parent A-C" in the columns be eliminated? I see this left join is the key for mapping parent to child ids

Comment: yes, you can eliminate the last row of my example by changing the `LEFT JOIN` to just `JOIN` which would be an inner join.

Comment: for some reasons, i could not get all the results for this, for instance if parent a suppose to have multiple record, it seems only 1 row can be produced for each parent recagardless of the child. I used left and join only

Comment: Thank you finnaly got it!!

Answer (score 0):

so happy that you shared your idea, played it around and combind EJ Egyed & MT0 's solutions (i cannot tagged your name's hyperlink, not sure if possible) and it seems getting all the records so far. I even double check to count the data childs manually and via script by parent_ids. Here is the final code, would love if you can add some points too.

```
SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT T2.pname                                          AS parent_name,
               t1.pname                                                AS child_name,
            
         MOD(
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.pname ORDER BY t1.pname) - 1,
           6
         ) + 1 AS child_num,
         TRUNC(
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.pname ORDER BY t1.pname) - 1)
           / 6
         ) AS rn
          FROM sourceTable t1   JOIN sourceTable t2 ON (t1.parent_id = t2.cmw_id)   ) 
       PIVOT (MIN (child_name) ch FOR child_num IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```